# How do you activate the pressure plates in Tianqiu Valley?

Tags: genshin-impact

[image]

It's these two pressure plates located in western portion of Tianqiu Valley here:

[image]

I've spent a bunch of time using Geo MC, trying a combination using two rocks on both plates, one rock on one plate and another character with Amber's Baron Bunny on another plate, and nothing has worked.  Both plates make the audio cue that they are both activated, but no chests show up. Are there even chests that show up here? Or is this puzzle meant for something else?

Comment: This puzzle is somewhat bugged. There is some advice about activation here https://www.reddit.com/r/Genshin_Impact/comments/jlz9yx/how_to_get_the_glitched_chest_in_tianqui_valley/ , I tried it couple of times and it didn't work for me. I decided to return there once it's actually fixed.

Comment: Does Amber's works for single press plates? Are there other multiple platforms puzzles? I've read you have to use 2 geo stones (you can have many, there is even canstellation increasing duration), but I can't recall other such puzzles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just solved that puzzle:

[image]

Here is step-by-step guide, I have no idea if any of the step is important, but I failed it at first (chest didn't spawned). If you fail - move away a bit and relog, then try again.

1. Face west.
2. Stand on left plate
3. Wait until it's lit
4. Drop geo-stone under your feets (hold <kbd>E</kbd> and rotate camera to find best spot)
5. Wait until you hear a sound (plate if fully pressed)
6. Climb the geo-stone, jump and glide a bit (I read this is important, maybe because plates are too close and gliding release trigger or something)
7. Stand on right panel and repeat same procedure with it.
8. After second plate is fully pressed (you should hear a sound) the chest should spawn.

Answer (score 3):

I used Amber to antagonize one of the geo hatchings on the ground into chasing me and managed to get it up on the platform with me. When it stood on one panel, I moved Amber to the other and the chest appeared. It was a fluke so I don't know how easily it can be replicated but it worked for me!